# Eclipse fails to start, gives - Failed to load the JNI shared Library

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I faced this issue many a times while working with a new setup or after a Java upgrade. Logical solution for this? Except replacing jvm.dll file?

Answer (score 0):

Never realized, but the solution is quite easy. As per my understanding:

**Observations:**
If you are using a 64bit Windows system, then you would notice that there are two **Program Files** folder in your C:/ Drive.

[image]

That means, **Program Files**, which contains 64-bit programs and applications, and. **Program Files (x86)**, which contains 32-bit programs and applications.

Now if you are using a 64bit system, then it is easy and recommended that you use softwares as well of 64bit. So your **Path** in System variables should contain the path details of your Java 64bit.

Now coming back to the original problem, here if we are on 64Bit Microsoft Windows system and wish to use 64bit Software (Eclipse for example), then let us set the **Path** for the 64bit Java.

Then make a simple test on command prompt.

-cmd

-java -version

[image]

Shows the 64bit Java VM is set to path.
Now Open your Eclipse and it do not show the Error.
Always remember that we should use:

64 bit OS

64 bit Java (with Path set for 64 bit Java)

64 bit Eclipse.